# Substitutions in Regular Expressions, and Replacement pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I spend 4 hours on this and still is not clear to me how should this work.
I want use logic from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Numbered) link. I want to transform

`Some123Grouping TO GroupingSome123`

I have 3 parts and should change order using replacement ($1, $2, $3)
Also I need something to transform

`name@gmail.com TO name`

It is not clear to me how to define replacement and what is captured in my case?

Thanks for help, I would relay appreciate it.

Comment: Please show us sample strings that you wish to transform. I can give you a regex use the stuff you have here, but will that port to your real data, I don't know. Do you literally want a regex to capture Some123Grouping or can you give me some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1, $2, etc. are referring to groups (i.e. the indexes of their appearance of declaration). So you need to define groups in your capturing regex. You do this by using parenthesis. For example:

```
Regex.Replace("Some123Grouping", @"(Some)(123)(Grouping)", @"$3$1$2")
```

yields "GroupingSome123".

Note that for better readability, groups can also be named and then referenced by their name. For example:

```
Regex.Replace("mr.smith@gmail.com", @"(?<name>.*)(@gmail.com)", @"${name}")
```

yields "mr.smith".

BTW, if you are looking for a general (non .NET specific but great) introduction to Regexes, I recommend [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 1):

Simply using your requirement yields

```
Regex.Replace("name@gmail.com", @"(name)(@gmail.com)", @"$1")
```

but I suspect what you want is more along the lines of

```
Regex.Replace("name@gmail.com", @"(\w*)(@.*)", @"$1")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly:

There is pattern with **Text** followed by **Numbers** followed by **Text** if that is correct this should meet your pattern:

```
string pattern = @"([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)";
```

The next step is getting the groups out if it like:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
var match = rx.Match(input);
```

Then your result may be obtained in 2 ways, the short version:

```
result = rx.Replace(input, "$3$1$2");
```

And the long version:

```
using System;               
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      string input = "Some123Grouping";
      string pattern = @"([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)";

      Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
      var match = rx.Match(input);

      Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}", 
                          match.Groups.Count, 
                          input);
      var newInput = "";
      for(int i= match.Groups.Count;i>0;i--){
        newInput +=  match.Groups[i];              
      }
      Console.WriteLine(newInput);
    }
}
```

Regarding your second issue it seems it is as simple as:

```
var result ="name@gmail.com".Split('@')[0];
```